# Annotation with public access only constraint

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I want to enforce that this annotation can only be placed on public members, either field or method. Is this possible? My brief research on this topic said no.

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CsvAttribute {
     String columnName();
     int position();
}
```

My goal is to achieve this without the try-catch block. Since I have access to the object can I do this without reflection?

```
public abstract class CsvExportable {

protected final Map<Integer, String> convertFieldsToMap(){
    final Method[] m = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(m)).stream()
            .filter(p -> p.isAnnotationPresent(CsvAttribute.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    p -> p.getAnnotation(CsvAttribute.class).position(),
                    p -> this.invokeGetter(p)));
}

private String invokeGetter(Method m){
    try {
        return Objects.toString(m.invoke(this), "");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        LOG.error("@CsvAttribute annotation must be placed on public getters!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

}
```

Comment: Even when the annotation is forced to be present at `public` members only, the compiler doesn’t know that the `Method` will always represent a `public` method. Therefore, it will keep insisting on catching `IllegalAccessException`. Further, it doesn’t matter whether the method is `public` or not, it may throw exceptions, hence, you always have to handle `InvocationTargetException`. In other words, there is no way around the try-catch block anyway. By the way, what’s the point of `StringUtils.EMPTY`, especially, as you are also using the straight-forward `""`, right in the same method?

Comment: Indeed I was not very consistent with the empty string reference here. I prefer using static constants to hardcoded literals.

Comment: Named constants are useful when the name tells you something but not when the name doesn’t tell you more than the constant itself. Everyone can see that `""` is an empty string, so saying the same thing just with the word `EMPTY` doesn’t justify adding a dependency to a 3rd party library. A different story would be the `"@CsvAttribute annotation must be placed on public getters!"` constant, which even contains the implicit assumption that the method is annotated with `@CsvAttribute` which is outside the scope of the `invokeGetter` method.

Comment: The idea here is that we extend exportable objects from the CsvExportable class. The convertFieldsToMap method is protected because of visibility reasons, and should not be overrided in a child class. So I missed to finalize it. Thus the invokeGetter private method will only be accessed by the convertFieldsToMap method. Thanks for the code review!

Comment: I know that the method is only invoked for appropriate methods, but it’s still the caller’s responsibility so the log message would be a natural candidate for a constant declared at class scope. Anyway, thinking about your actual problem, I’m wondering if you considered the opposite; when you utilize the `java.lang.invoke` API, you could drop the requirement that the methods have to be `public`.

Comment: By the way, `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(m)).stream()` is doing unnecessary detours twice: there is no need to copy the `List` created via `Arrays.asList(m)` into an `ArrayList`, as `Arrays.asList(m).stream()` would do as well, but you can even create a `Stream` in the first place without any `List`: just `Arrays.stream(m)`.

Comment: What would I gain from dropping the public requirement? The try-catch block would remain, with an additional `.setAccessible(true)` call.

Comment: Well, that’s what I said in my first comment, even when you enforce the method to be public, the try-catch block would remain. But I’m not talking about using `setAccessible(true)` but to use the `java.lang.invoke` API which allows the caller to transfer the necessary access rights to the utility method, so it can’t fail due to insufficient access rights. There’s also the option to generate `Function` objects for the accessor methods, which you would do only once per class, so the subsequent use would not require try catch blocks anymore. The initialization would be more complicated though.

Answer (score 1):

No to my knowledge you cannot do this without reflection considering you need to do annotation processing. You can use Modifier#isPublic to determine if the Field or Method is public. You should also use ElementType.METHOD if you want to support methods as well as indicated.

On an unrelated note, feel free to check out [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph) or [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) for some reflection apis that might make your life easier.

```java
// if a method or field
if (!Modifier.isPublic(method)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Modifier must be public.");
}
// if a field
if (!Modifier.isPublic(field)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Modifier must be public.");

}
```

```java
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD })
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to configure that in the annotation itself, but you can do it in your compile time annotation processor if you have one. Simply throw an exception if the annotated element is not valid.

If you're only processing the annotation at runtime, that won't help much. You can trigger a runtime exception, but no compilation error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know by any chance how does Lombok (and similar libraries) solve this? It seems like they are processing annotations during compilation to generate the boilerplate codes.

Comment: @Andrew yes, Lombok does annotation processing at compile time. It also does a lot more, not-quite-officially supported things during compilation. There's a lot of other projects that are a lot simpler in their annotation processing, like [Google Auto](https://github.com/google/auto)